# emoji-picker focus using js (or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

There is a way for focus this textarea using js (or jquery)?

http://onesignal.github.io/emoji-picker/demo/

i have tried with:
`$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor").focus()` and `$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor").trigger('click')` without success.

Answer (score 1):

The textarea seems to be a div tag and a div tag can be focused if it has a tabindex attribute set to -1.
Try this

```
$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

Comment: Exactly. That helped me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but for me the following did it:

```
// Mousedown on #sendBtn submits message
    $('#sendBtn').mousedown(function (editor) {

        $('#sendBtn').click();
        // clear textArea after mousedown on #sendBtn
        $('#chatTextarea').data("emojioneArea").setText('');

        // keep focus on editor after mousedown on #sendBtn
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#emojioneArea").data("emojioneArea").editor.focus();
        }, 1)
    });
```

Without setTimeout it didn't work. Don't ask me why. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Both the editor should be `.focus()` and `EmojiArea_WYSIWYG` in `jquery.emojiarea.js` must have propery `hasFocus=True`.